# Different notations of Python class/functions argument definitions

Tags: python

`class defaultdict(builtins.dict)
|  defaultdict(default_factory[, ...]) --> dict with default factory`

I know how to use defaultdict by following various tutorials, which is default_factory is an optional value (default is None) and we can initialize a defaultdict with initial key-value pairs in various ways, such as:

```
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: 0, [('a', 2), ('b', 3)])
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: 0, (('a', 2), ('b', 3)))
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: 0, a=2, b=3)
```

But how can I understand the same by simply looking at defaultdict helper documentations? For example, here the arguments of defaultdict is  **(default_factory[, ...])**.
It doesn't provide any default value for default_factory and what does **[, ...]** mean?

Could someone please provide a link/documentation which explains all these notations?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation

Comment: > a phrase enclosed in square brackets ([ ]) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory attribute; it defaults to None. All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments.